# Apache + php5 problem after 12.04.3 to 14.04.i do release upgrade (server)

Tags: apache2, php, do-release-upgrade

I did a 'do-release-upgrade' Most upgrade went fine. But the upgrade from Apache 2.2.22 to 2.4.7 went wrong. There seems to be something wrong with the php5 apache module.

I get the following error message:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 203 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 
1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/module
/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: cannot open shared   
object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

How to fix this problem? I'll hope there is easy way to solve this problem. :)

Comment: In [your recently deleted "answer" post](http://askubuntu.com/a/520055/22949), I think you mentioned [the existing answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/520039/22949) worked. If you consider [Benoit's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/520039/22949) to have solved the problem you asked about in *this* question, I'd recommend you accept that answer by clicking the gray check mark next to (to the left of) it. ([More info here about that.](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers))

Answer (score 5):

From the error message, the PHP5 Apache module is not present where it should.

First, check the installation status of the PHP5 module package :

```
user@hostname:~$ dpkg -l |grep libapache2-mod-php5
ii  libapache2-mod-php5              5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.3               amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
```

If the result is not like above (a line starting by `ii`) then the module is not or badly installed.

If `dpkg` returns no line, do :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

If `dpkg` returns a line not starting with `ii`, do :

```
sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Comment: Note `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install libapache2-mod-php5` will do the same thing as the second method (under "*If `dpkg` returns a line not starting with `ii`*"), but will wait to uninstall software until any necessary files for reinstalling it have been downloaded. This may be considered preferable in case of a network interruption (and because it requires, in a sense, fewer steps). It can also replace the first method, as it should succeed nicely even if the package isn't already installed. (So the initial `dpkg -l | grep ...` step could even be skipped.)